# How do I get rid of the VMware "Unidentified Networks" in Windows Vista and 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-vista, file-sharing, vmware-player

After installing VMware in Windows Vista or 7, there are two public networks that can't be identified, but upon further inspection are virtual networks created by VMware. The problem is when you're on a Home network, these "Unidentified Networks" are still there and mess up file sharing settings, among other things.

Comment: I don't mind with the unidentified networks thingy but I don't like the fact that it messes with file sharing

Comment: That is nice. Do you also have a question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per [this site](http://aspoc.net/archives/2008/10/30/unidentified-network-issue-with-vmwares-virtual-nics-in-vista/):

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. Click the following subkey:

   `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`
3. Browse through the 00xx subkeys until you find the REG_SZ VMNet subkey with a value of either “\DosDevices\VMnet8” or “\DosDevices\VMnet1” (default values)
4. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
5. Type *NdisDeviceType, and then press Enter.
6. On the Edit menu, click Modify.
7. Type 1, and then click OK.
8. Exit Registry Editor.
9. Disable & re-enable the VMWare NICs
10. Log-out of your Windows account and log back in.
11. Done

Or, optionally, use [this powershell script](http://www.nivot.org/2008/09/05/VMWareVMNETAdaptersTriggeringPublicProfileForWindowsFirewall.aspx) to do the same thing automatically. This is most useful in Windows 7 which has PowerShell built in.

Comment: BTW, still coming back to this almost a year later as a reference every time I need to fix this on a new system / install of Vmware. :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to the *Windows Firewall* properties and **disable** the firewall for the *VMWare adapter*.

Comment: This seems like a good answer too. Does it work? I'll try :)

Comment: Can you provide steps for this? It's not clear.

Comment: I've had this issue when deploying Virtual Machines to RDS... This worked great in this circumstance too, thanks!